# Screensaver to cycle through webpages?

Tags: ruby, screensaver

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to create a screensaver that can cycle through some webpages?  I would like to create a screensaver that displays various dashboard and statistics pages that are available in our Hudson CI server.  This is a windows machine, with firefox and IE available.

Extra bonus points if I can do it in ruby! :-)

Cheers,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after a few false starts I found a pretty simple solution.  I used Visual Studio Express Edition to create a windows forms application.  You just need to drag a WebBrowser control onto the form and resize to full screen at startup.  Then all you have to do is hook up the event handlers to deal with the mouse and keyboard.

Some more details here:

- [Blog post on how I made the screensaver](http://meekrosoft.wordpress.com/2009/12/30/a-windows-screensaver-to-cycle-through-webpages/)
- [Source code on github](http://github.com/meekrosoft/windows_web_screensaver)

Answer (score 1):

I programmed a lot of screensavers in Delphi, but I think the following should be applicable to all sorts of development environments.
You create the main form of your screensaver and put an IE-control on it (or if your development environment does not support it, an OLE-container) and then create a timer which changes the webpage shown by the IE-control.
Sorry no solution in ruby....